I want to plot the image of some region by a map
We want to plot the region $\operatorname{f}\left(D\right)$, where
$$
\operatorname{f}:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}, \left(x,y\right)\mapsto \left(x,y + x^{2}\right)
$$
and $D := \left\{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}\mid x > 0\ \mbox{and}\ x + y > 0\right\}$.
Here, $\operatorname{f}$ and $D$ are just examples, and I would like to write about general $\operatorname{f}$ and $D$.
Please provide the $\,\,\,\tt Mathematica\ $ code for this case that I can modify myself for general cases.


ParametricPlot with RegionFunction.

Clear["Global`*"];
f[{x_, y_}] := {x, y + x^2};
ParametricPlot[f[{u, v}], {u, -20, 20}, {v, -20, 20}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, u > 0 && u + v > 0], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2]



RegionPlot the domain and using DisplayFunction.

f[{x_, y_}] := {x, y + x^2};
RegionPlot[x > 0 && x + y > 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 80, 
 DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real} :> f@{x, y}]]



Thank you very much! It is solved!

Another way is as follows.
r = TransformedRegion[ImplicitRegion[{x > 0, x + y > 0},{x, y}],{Indexed[#,1], 
 Indexed[#, 1]^2 + Indexed[#, 2]} &];
Region[r]


In fact, the r region is unbounded and only a part of it is displayed by the Region command.

The description of r as an implicit region can be obtained by RegionConvert[r, "Implicit"] which results in ImplicitRegion[\[FormalX]>0&&\[FormalX]^2<\[FormalX]+\[FormalY],{\[FormalX],\[FormalY]}].

Thank you very much! It is solved!
